# Problem with beaker hanging on aws-sdk awaiting response from private ip

Tags: aws-sdk, puppet, beaker

It will of course never get response on the private ip.

Associate public ip is by default disabled on my subnet-id. Is there anyway to tell beaker to set associate_public_ip_address true?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need Beaker, you may have better success with Packer here.

Comment: It's just a very very simple property that is available thorugh aws-sdk :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new property *associate_public_ip_address* that can be defined to true, false or left out (falling back to default) to [beaker-aws](https://github.com/puppetlabs/beaker-aws). It has been released as [beaker-aws](https://github.com/puppetlabs/beaker-aws) version 0.8.0.